# Fading of the URL in Safari 6's Unified Search and URL Field 

Tags: safari, url

With Safari 6, the omnibar fades the non-server part of the URL, so that the actual server name is more visible. Presumably, this is to reduce phishing attacks.

However, I find that the remainder of the url is hard to read, and to be honest, when developing websites, that is the part I care much more about.

Is there any way to have it so that the whole url is the same?

Comment: Maybe use something else other than safari?

Comment: Google chrome does it too: but not quite as aggressively. I do test in other browsers, but prefer to use WebKit-based browsers initially: purely for the developer tools. And the window colours in Chrome don't quite look right :)

Comment: If it is unclear and you want to read it, click on the address bar to activate it.

Comment: From Gerry in the comments: Click on the address bar to activate it and the font will be restored to bold.

Comment: #1: It's not bold, it's black as opposed to grey.

Comment: #2: That' a fairly annoying step to have to take: I then need to move my mouse up to a small target? I could Cmd-L, which is faster, but still a step I'd rather not have to do.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above by dan8394, you can click the omnibar, reactivating the full URI. Unfortunately, there is not an option for changing this in Safari, nor does a hook exist in AppleScript. To the best of my knowledge, the only way this can be changed would be through a Safari extension. However, from what I have found, this is hard-coded into Safari itself and there isn't an option or a flag to change that will affect it. Sorry.

Good luck and happy browsing!