# Is there any significance to the dimmed text in Safari 6?

Tags: safari, macos, url

Text in the address bar of Safari 6.0 is [displayed differently](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57810/4395) than in previous versions. Prior to 6.0, all text was black

[image]

but in 6.0, all text after the domain is grey:

[image]

Is there any significance to this? Does it correspond to some new feature of Safari?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of this is to make **the domain** of the site you're visiting blatantly obvious. Many phishing scams will use URLs that look very similar, but not *exactly* identical to the site they're trying to mimic (using things like, for example, `paypal.com.mysupersketchydomain.ru`), and this technique (now used in most modern browsers) helps to mitigate that risk even for non-tech-savvy users.

Comment: Sure enough, Wikipedia says this is what's going on (without citing a source though). But it strikes me as [implausible that this has any effect](http://www.pcworld.com/article/125739/privacy_watch_protect_yourself_with_an_antiphishing_toolbar.html) at all, and can't be worth the [cost to usability](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57810/safari-6-omni-bar-url-fading).

Comment: I might add that Firefox and Chrome have both had this feature for a long time, and it's about time Safari caught up. :-) That and the omnibar...