# Can Safari be configured to not hide the full URL path in the omnibar?

Tags: safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fading of the URL in Safari 6's Unified Search and URL Field](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57810/fading-of-the-url-in-safari-6s-unified-search-and-url-field) 
>   [How to fix Safari 6 on Mountain Lion that doesn't show the full URL in the address bar unless I click it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61230/how-to-fix-safari-6-on-mountain-lion-that-doesnt-show-the-full-url-in-the-addre)

The latest Safari version (6.0 (8536.25)) now hides the URL path from the address bar. Instead, it only showing the hostname (e.g. right now I only see "apple.stackexchange.com"). Clicking on the bar to edit will revert it to the full URL (e.g. apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Note that this is different to previous behavior where the URL path was still shown, albeit in a lighter shade of gray. Now it's completely gone, and only clicking will bring it back.

This is very annoying, and downright crippling when developing web applications. Is there a way to disable this behavior? I combed through the preferences dialog but couldn't find anything remotely related.

Comment: I very much hope that there might be a hidden preference that could revert this display and possibly the coloring where the text after the host name (starting with the /) is a dimmer grey to let the host have more visual contrast.